# How can I get express.js to catch and report runtime exceptions in AJAX calls

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I've found that when I have runtime errors (for example, reading an undefined property from an object) in a GET handler in express.js, Express is great at giving me feedback in the browser as to what the problem is and with a full stack trace.

However, when I have runtime errors as a result of an Ajax POST call, I don't get the same level of feedback and the Node console is sadly silent on the matter.

Is this an Express configuration issue?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Found the answer to my own questions...

You need to configure express's error handler to dump exceptions.

```
    app.use(express.errorHandler({showStack: true, dumpExceptions: true}));
```

Comment: Worth mentioning that these flags are now the default and that "`errorHandler()` is now a development only middleware". https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/commit/a68b1c9b4389801c4c58c07fc91b65b19687d91c#lib/middleware/errorHandler.js